# Prove that the transitive closure of a relation is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I've been thinking about this question for a while but can't exactly figure out how to do it. I'm thinking it has something to do with showing that given $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$ within compositions of $R$, then $(x, z)$ is present within the closure. For context, the book I'm using defines the transitive closure of $R$ as $R^+ = \bigcup_{0 < n \in \mathbb{N}} R^n$, where $R^1 = R$, $R^{n+1} = R^n | R$, the composition of $R^n$ and $R$, and $R$ is a binary relation.

Comment: Suggestion: write out from the book definition what x(R+)y and y(R+)z each mean. [be sure to use different letters, say m and n, for the number of iterates in each case.] Then think about what composition means.

Comment: $R^+R^+=\bigcup_{p,q\ge1}R^{p+q}=\bigcup_{n\ge2}R^n\subset R^+.$

Comment: How are you defining "transitive closure"?  My definition is "the smallest (i.e. unique minimal) transitive relation which contains the original"...which, of course, makes the question trivial.